# Sum lines with duplicate values in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, sum

I need a macro to look at the list of data below, provide a count of the number of instances it appears and sum the value of each of them. I know a pivot table or series of formulas could work but I'm doing this for a coworker and it has to be a 'one click here' kinda deal. The data is as follows:

```
A        B
Smith   200.00
Dean    100.00
Smith   100.00
Smith    50.00
Wilson   25.00
Dean     25.00
Barry   100.00
```

The end-result would look like this

```
Smith    3     350.00
Dean     2     125.00
Wilson   1      25.00
Barry    1     100.00
```

Comment: Have your co-worker learn how to use Excel.

Comment: I'd move it to a database, and use a query something like: `select name, count(*), sum(price) from your_table, group by name`

Answer (score 3):

Just create the pivot table in a new sheet, that references that data. To update it tell your co-worker to right click the pivot table and select refresh. No need for a macro or code for this.

Answer (score 2):

Recorded macro to create a pivot table that does what you want.

```
Sub Macro1()

'Who Cost
'Smith   200
'Dean    100
'Smith   100
'Smith   50
'Wilson  25
'Dean    25
'Barry   100

    Range("A1:B8").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Sheet1!R1C1:R8C2").CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="[Book1]Sheet1!R1C4", _
        TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion10
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Who")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable1").PivotFields("Cost"), "Sum of Cost", xlSum
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable1").PivotFields("Cost"), "Sum of Cost2", xlSum
    Range("E1").Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").DataPivotField
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    Range("E2").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Sum of Cost").Function = _
        xlCount
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel provides these things

sumif()
countif()
Data, Filter, Advanced Filter, Unique records only

Gives you all you need, you can record as a macro.

Comment: JD,

would you elaborate on how to set that up?

Thanks,

John

Comment: Put your test data into columns A and B rows 1 to 8
In C2 enter =COUNTIF($A$2:$A$8,A2) and copy it down to cells below
In D2 enter =SUMIF($A$2:$A$8,A2,$B$2:$B$8) and copy it down
What you have then is every time Smith appears you get 3 in column C and 350 in column D, but you see that 3 times because Smith appears 3 times. You can use the Advanced Filter to hide the duplicates.

Comment: Pivot Table is much easier to set up, easier for the user to change, and less complicated. Moreover, your suggestion would be better served using Array Formulas.

Answer (score -1):

Are you allowed to mess with the data? You could sort it by column A and then use the subtotal capability, at changes in column A sum column B and show total in column B (which I think are the default settings anyway).

If you may not sort it then I'd think literally just copying it to a new sheet and sorting the copy of it would be the easiest way forward.

[Sorry, I forgot the "count" bit. You can add a new column filled with 1s and subtotal that in the same way.]